# Protractor and click item for loader

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I m having some trouble testing the apparition of a loader when clicking a button.

I have the following three test :

```
  it('#exigence1 - display a failing message on button fail ', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    page.getButtonFail().click();
    expect(page.getErrorMessage()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('#exigence2 - display a loader on waiting list ', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    page.getButtonLoad().click();
    expect(page.getLoader()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('#exigence3 - display a list of items on message ', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    page.getButtonLoad().click();
    expect(page.getPokeList()).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

When I click the getButtonLoad, I display a loader during the remote fetch. I need to test that this loader appears on the page, but my previous second test doesn't pass.

Here's my implementation :

```
 buttonClick() {
    this.showError = false;
    this.displayLoader = true;
    this.http.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.pokemons = res.results;
        this.displayLoader = false;
      });
  }
```

With my page definition :

```
export class ProtractorDemonstrationPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getPokeList() {
    return element(by.css('.poke-list')).getText();
  }

   getButtonLoad() {
    return element(by.css('.btn-primary'));
  }

   getButtonFail() {
    return element(by.css('.btn-warn'));
  }

   getErrorMessage() {
    return element(by.css('.panel-danger')).getText();
  }

    getLoader() {
    return element(by.css('.loader')).getText();
  }
}
```

I don't know at all how to make a test that validate this case.

EDIT : What I see there is that the click, when clicked, is waiting for the function to finish its stuff before getting to the next instruction. Here's my problem. I need to click, and don't wait for the async stuff and directly check that my loader is there.

EDIT 2 : Here's the code of the function :

```
 load() {
    this.showError = false;
    this.displayLoader = true;
    this.http.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.pokemons = res.results;
        this.displayLoader = false;
      });
  }
```

Does

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with page.getLoader() and your expect statement. With the page.getLoader() call you are returning the text of that element but in your expect statement you are expecting this function to return a boolean value.

You should change your page.getLoader() to return:

```
return element(by.css('.loader')).isDisplayed();
```

or use keep using .getText() but change your expect statement to:

```
expect(page.getLoader()).toBe('This string');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not working. It seems that protractor waits for the end of the async stuff before making its expectation. I don't know how to prevent this...

Comment: It seems like a timing issue, try throwing it in a promise:
page.getButtonLoad().click().then(function () {
expect(page.getLoader()).toBeTruthy();
});

Comment: Have you confirmed that each individual action is performing as expected? For example are you certain that page.getButtonLoad().click(); is triggering the "loader"? I'm not sure if you are already familiar with Protractor's elementExplorer, but it's a great tool to use to test these kind of things. In this case I would use it to click getButtonLoad() and figure out a way of checking if the "loader" is displayed.

Comment: In fact, it's displayed in the chrome browser that protractor opens when the element is clicked. And I can see it in the dom on a real case (click manually the button)

Comment: What kind of result do you get if you use this expected condition statement before the expect statement  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('.loader')), 5000);